Have trouble with a react deployment to Vercel. index-C5K1NyVi.js:1 Failed to load module
My deployment appears to go through no problem after several docs issues but now I get an error  index-C5K1NyVi.js:1 Failed to load module
This file does not exist, there is an index.js in the assets folder which had a hashed name previously but not any longer. Everything works OK locally so I assume there has to be a problem in the local configuration. this is the address https://eoin-mcdonnell.vercel.app/ github: https://github.com/oldmcdonnell/portfolio
vercel.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "package.json",
        "use": "@vercel/static-build",
        "config": {
          "distDir": "docs"
        }
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/portfolio/assets/(.*).js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/javascript"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/portfolio/assets/(.*).css",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "text/css"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/portfolio/(.*)",
        "dest": "/portfolio/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/(.*)",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/portfolio/',
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    hot: true
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'docs',
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].js',
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].js',
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  }
})

package.json

{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build --outDir docs",
    "preview-build": "vite preview --outDir docs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "sass": "^1.75.0",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^20.12.1",
    "npm": "^10.5.0"
  }
}


config-overrides.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: function(config, env) {
    config.output = {
      ...config.output,
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs'),
      publicPath: '/'
    };
    return config;
  }
};

I have tried reverting back to older config files, I have created a new vite project and tried using it's fresh and clean configuration files.
